# How to plot a point-to-point alignment between two sequences of datapoints?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working on time series with Dynamic Time Warping. I need to plot the alignment between the datapoints of two sequences:

```
t=[t1,t2,t3,...,tx]
s=[s1,s2,s3,...,sy]
```

The length of both sequences may vary. I also have which points match, say:

```
[(1,1),(1,2), (2,2), (3,3), (4,3), (4,4)]
```

This is read as:

```
t[1] matches s[1]   
t[1] matches s[2]   
t[2] matches s[2]   
...   
t[4] matches s[4]
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Or even better, like this (i.e. nothing but the two sequences and their alignment):
[image]

I'm aware of the existence of the `dtw` pacakge though it doesn't seem to include a method to plot the alignment. I'm fairly new to plotting using Python so I'm still in the dark when it comes to matplotlib and numpy, or at least I'm not sure about the best approach to go about it using them.

Summarizing, I just need to know how to plot both sequences, one on top of the other (subplots might help, I believe?) and draw a line between each datapoint using Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to plot s and t with plt.plot. Doing the lines between them is a little trickier. I'm assuming that the x-axis corresponds to the xth element of both s and t. In that case, if the ith element of s and the jth element of t are paired, you could plot the line between them with `plt.plot((i, j), (s[i], t[j]), color = 'black')`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plot signals
plt.plot(y1, label = 'Signal 1')
plt.plot(y2, label = 'Signal 2')
#plot alignment
for i, j in matches:
    plt.plot((i, j), (y1[i], y2[j]), color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Amy, this is awesome, that's very close to what I want. The x axis indeed corresponds to both sequences though I need to plot them separately. That's why I wondered if subplots could be useful though another approach would be just adding n number to each one of the points in y1 and have it plotted along y2 within the _same_ plot, and then remove the x and y axes to get something like the second picture in my OP.

Comment: @absay, it's not clear to me what you mean by plotting the sequences separately. You don't need mutiple subplots in order to make them different lines, and if they're on different subplots, you would have a hard time drawing lines between them. If you're worried about overlap, you could just add to the y-values as you suggest, or you could do something like this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Do you mean remove the grid / axes / axis labels etc?  if so, I'm sure it can be added to this answer...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. I have overcome the problem of "plotting both sequences" apart. That is no longer an issue. The problem now is that, following Amy's code, I get what I want but it doesn't work when both sequences are not of the same length. For example, if `t` has 9 items and `s` has 7, I get an Index out of range error. I can't figure out how to get around this. It's the only and last thing I need. I appreciate any help.

Comment: @absay, you shouldn't get an index out of range error as long as you choose the numbers in `matches` properly. Can you post an example of some code that didn't work for you?

Comment: @Amy, you're absolutely right. I was having the classic "swapped axes" problem, so instead of `y1[i],y2[j]`, I just had to switch it to `y1[j],y2[i]` for the second argument in `plt.plot`. Thank you very much for the help and patience.